# redirect select record error to current page

Tags: apex, visualforce, redirect, errormessages

I have a page that filter records based on a field, when a user search for a record that do not exist the following error page is displayed

[image]

I want to display a customized error like "record does not exist" in the current visualforce page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a check on the list you get from your Select query if its size is 0 and add an Apex Message. I hope your method in controller is returning PageReference.

```
if(myList.size() == 0){
ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Query returned zero records!');
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
return null;
}
```

In your Visualforce page, add a tag

```
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
```